# What is the difference between "connect with compass" and "connect with mongo shell" in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, dart, mongodb-compass, mongodb-shell

I've been trying to follow a tutorial of [How to connect Flutter and MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juKDXPk7kU4&t=241s) where he connects MongoDB with Terminal (Command Prompt). For some reason I couldn't connect with MongoDB using Shell, So I thought if I could connect MongoDB using Mongo Compass because I only have that.
Could anyone please suggest a solution? If "connect with compass" and "connect with mongo shell" are same then how can I use compass to integrate MongoDB and flutter or if these two are not same suggest a solution to this. **Please help me this is Important!!**

Answer (score 1):

Mongo Compass is GUI interface for your mongodb. You can select connect with compass and get your connection string then you can use it in Flutter for connect your mongodb.

Comment: Correct - but Mongo Compass is typically more used to import/export data and manage the collections in the database. While Mongo DB shell is more for console type debugging. This being said, Mongo DB shell is more clunky to use on windows, imho.  And Mongo Compass works well on Windows.